# How do I get pixi to read 8 digit hex codes?

Tags: vue.js, colors, vuetify.js, picker, pixi.js

I'm using Vuetify's color picker which has options for hexa, hsla and rgba. I am using hexa but am willing to use any option that will work.

It seems that Pixi can only understand 6 digits hex codes with 0x in front of it.
I want to be able to use Vuetify's slider and translate the 8 digit hex code to pixi.

Here is what I've tried:

`this.sketcher.color = this.color.replace(/\x23/g, '0')`
This removes the '#' (ascii 23) from the front and adds 0 in it's place. I read the 0x is for 6 digit hex and 0 is for octal; which I was hoping meant 8 digit hexa codes but it appears that's not correct.

I've also found a workaround to remove the last two digits from the hex value but that removes the transparency.

Is there a way to push over my 8 digit hexa value to pixi in a way that pixi will understand it and display it accordingly?? I'm using it to sketch shapes btw. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For a color in string format `'#RRGGBBAA'` few operations need to be done so it can be used with PIXI. You need to convert the string to a *number* and also *extract the alpha component* to a separate variable. This can be done like this:

1. Remove the `#` symbol from the beginning of the color string: `color.slice(1)`
2. Convert color string to number type with the `parseInt(...)` global function.
3. Extract RGB values from color number with bit shifting.
4. Extract alpha component (last two characters) by bit manipulation.

```js
// Convert color string to a number
const colorString = '#ffcc33aa';
const colorNumber = parseInt(colorString.slice(1), 16);

// Extract color components from color number
const rgb = colorNumber >>> 8;
const alpha = (colorNumber & 0xff) / 255;

// Apply obtained color components to a PIXI sprite
sprite.tint = rgb;
sprite.alpha = alpha;
```